# How to only log to pm2 stream log?

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

i am running express js framework with pm2 with file process.json

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "api-starter",
      "script": "server.js",
      "watch": false,
      "ignore_watch": [
        "/[\s\S].spec.js$/",
        "node_modules",
        "temp",
        "logs/*"
      ],
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "instances": 1,
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ",
      "error_file": "logs/error.log",
      "out_file": "logs/out.log",
      "min_uptime": 500,
      "max_restarts": 10,
      "restart_delay": 1000,
      "env_development": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "watch": true
      },
      "env_production": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and i use npm package `pretty-error`, it's awesome package make my error stack look nicer. but when pm2 try to save in log file it's become unreadable, is there a way to avoid pm2 log it to file but keep in stream mode.

```
2017-12-14 01:22:35+07:00:   [0m[97m[41mReferenceError[0m[90m:[0m[37m [0m[97masd is not defined[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mindex.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m5[0m[37m [0m[37mrouter.get[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90mC:/Users/mungil/Desktop/express-api-starter/app/routes/index.js:5:43[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mlayer.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m95[0m[37m [0m[37mLayer.handle [as handle_request][0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/layer.js:95:5[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mroute.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m137[0m[37m [0m[37mnext[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/route.js:137:13[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mroute.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m112[0m[37m [0m[37mRoute.dispatch[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/route.js:112:3[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mlayer.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m95[0m[37m [0m[37mLayer.handle [as handle_request][0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/layer.js:95:5[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mindex.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m281[0m[37m [0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:281:22[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mindex.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m335[0m[37m [0m[37mFunction.process_params[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:335:12[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mindex.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m275[0m[37m [0m[37mnext[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:275:10[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mindex.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m174[0m[37m [0m[37mFunction.handle[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:174:3[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mindex.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m47[0m[37m [0m[37mrouter[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[express-api-starter]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:47:12[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

add `/dev/null` as the value of `out_file`, 'err_file' and `log_file` in **process.json** entry

```
{
  "out_file": "/dev/null",
  "err_file": "/dev/null",
  "log_file": "/dev/null",
}
```

[More Details](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#disable-logging)